# Big O help Discrete Math

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Is 17x+11 a function of O(x^2)?

My steps so far:

17x+11 < c.x^2 where x>k
17x+11/x^2 < C

Im not too sure what to do next so I'd really appreciate if it someone could guide me.

This question was not answered. The link that was provided exceeds what we have to know to solve this problem.

Comment: Yeah, sometimes people here are too quick on the closing trigger. You want a $c > 0$ such that $17x+11<cx^2$ for all $x>k$. Since $x^2$ grows much faster than $17x$, try $c=1$. Then $17x+11<x^2$ is equivalent to saying $x^2-17x-11>0$. A little algebra will tell you that this is true for all $x>(17+\sqrt{289+44})/2\approx 17.62$ so $k=18$ will work here.

Comment: If the duplicate doesn't answer the question, please edit the question to explain why not, or study the material in the duplicate and ask a new question and make clear in the new question why the answers there don't answer your question.  If there is some constraint on what methods you are willing to use, please make sure to specify them in the question.

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!